# Mutex for websocket in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a problem, and I don't know exactly what to search for. 
I have a spring boot app which broadcast the message via web socket with a stomp javascript client. The question is if I can put a lock on the message when it is sent because I want no one to send another message at the same time. The system that I want to make is like a traffic light.
If you can give me an example or what to look for.

Comment: Probably, you would want to look at Message queuing systems like Kafka etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `synchronized` keyword and wait for the client response.  `synchronized` keyword ensures that only one thread can execute the method at the same time. And you need client response because you can sequentially send two messages, say in two seconds interval, but your client will get them at the same time. Response can be some dummy ok-message.

```
public class Traffic {
    synchronized void Send() {
        // write message to websocket
        // read response from websocket 
    }
}
```

Comment: the synchronized method should be on the controller where or on the websocket configuration?

Comment: @duricuvlad on the controller